# How can i pass the address of a draggable google map marker into an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I want to pass the address of a google draggable map marker into a field and then submit it into a column in mysql database. I found the code below which is exactly what i want but i want to put the "Closest matching address" result inside an input field. How can i do that ?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function geocodePosition(pos) {
 geocoder.geocode({
latLng: pos
}, function(responses) {
if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
  updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
} else {
  updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
}
});
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
latLng.lat(),
latLng.lng()
].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function initialize() {
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
zoom: 8,
center: latLng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latLng,
title: 'Point A',
map: map,
draggable: true
});

// Update current position info.
updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
geocodePosition(latLng);

// Add dragging event listeners.
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
});
}

// Onload handler to fire off the app.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
#mapCanvas {width: 500px;height: 400px;float: left;}
#infoPanel {float: left;margin-left: 10px;}
#infoPanel div {margin-bottom: 5px;}
</style>

<div id="mapCanvas"></div>
<div id="infoPanel">
<b>Marker status:</b>
<div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
<b>Current position:</b>
<div id="info"></div>
<b>Closest matching address:</b>
<div id="address"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is an answer to similar kind of  [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12829342/1578908

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
<div id="address"></div>

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}
```

To:

```
<input id="address" />

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
    document.getElementById('address').value = str;
}
```