# google maps api - error -Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: in property latLng: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get formatted_address from give lat, lng but I am faced with error "Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: in property latLng: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number"
Iam using GMap.js
Below is my code:
First I get current location of user

```js
 GMaps.geolocate({
            success: function (position) {
getSetFormattedAddressLatLng( {
                    H: position.coords.latitude,
                    L: position.coords.longitude
                });
            },
            error: function (error) {
                notificationService.error('Geolocation failed: ' + error.message);
            },
            not_supported: function () {
                alert("Your browser does not support geolocation");
            },
            always: function () {
                //alert("Done!");
            }
        });
```

On success to get current location of the user I call function getSetFormattedAddressLatLng(), the funciton looks as below

```js
function getSetFormattedAddressLatLng(latLng) {
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({
                    latLng: latLng
                }, function (responses) {
                    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
                        //set the formatted_address on originOrDestination               

                    } else {
                        debugger;
                        notificationService.error('Cannot determine address at this location.');
                    }
                });
}
```

But when I call geocoder.geocoder() I get the error message "Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: in property latLng: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number".
What am I doing wrong?

Regards,
Chidan

Comment: related question: [How to get the formated address from a dragged marker in Google Version Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828044/how-to-get-the-formated-address-from-a-dragged-marker-in-google-version-maps)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a structure like this to the `geocoder.geocode` constructor:

```js
{
   H: position.coords.latitude,
   L: position.coords.longitude
}
```

Which isn't valid.  Try just doing this (I'm assuming `position` is already a LatLng object):

```js
getSetFormattedAddressLatLng(position);
```

or possibly

```js
getSetFormattedAddressLatLng(position.coords);
```

At the very worst, you could create a new LatLng object:

```js
GMaps.geolocate({
        success: function (position) {
            getSetFormattedAddressLatLng(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
        },
```

Comment: Nopes still the same error, "position" I realized is constructor for Geoposition. I realize latLng should be a constructor but I dontknow of which function, could you please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for hint from Duncan, solved it.
solved by creating latLng object as below and then passing it to geocoder.geocode()

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
```