# Dynamic reverse geocoding from map center on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geocoding

For a poll that I am working on I have this map that geocodes your location and centers the map into that specific spot. Through jquery I get both longitude and latitude to fill that poll fields from wherever the center is in my map.

What I want to know is how to add the address as a 3rd poll field and just like the coordinates to get it dynamically when my map center changes. I've seen something similar in this post, where they get the address dynamically from a dragged marker:
[How to get the formatted address from a dragged marker in Google Version Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828044/how-to-get-the-formated-address-from-a-dragged-marker-in-google-version-maps)

Here you can see my working map:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation Flecker</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;        
        padding: 0px
      }
 #map-canvas {
    position: relative;
}

#map-canvas:after {
    width: 66px;
    height: 66px;
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin: -66px 0 0 -44px;
    background: url('https://storage.googleapis.com/operations_poligone/iconos/Stick01.png');
    background-size: 88px 66px; 
    pointer-events: none; 
}
      
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?V=3.exp&key=AIzaSyDgwY_XXwSE2v-ZCWziaJ6qjuTuiBJck9A
&libraries=visualization&libraries=places"></script>

        <script
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      
var map;

function initialize() {

 var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 11,
                    scrollwheel: true,
                    panControl: true,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    scaleControl: false,
                    disableDefaultUI: true,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.038235, -98.219530),
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
                    }
  };
  
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions); 
  
  
      //Retrive the center location
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, "center_changed", function() {
        var lat = map.getCenter().lat();
        var lng = map.getCenter().lng();
        $('#lat').val(lat);
        $('#lng').val(lng); 
      });  
  
  
  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);
  document.getElementById('lat').value = position.coords.latitude;
  document.getElementById('lng').value = position.coords.longitude;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        title: 'Ubicación GPS',
     icon:'https://storage.googleapis.com/operations_poligone/iconos/GPS_P06.png',
        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
      });

      map.setZoom(16);
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Turn GPS on';
  } else {
    var content = 'Try with your fingers';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(19.038235, -98.219530),
    content: content,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,-30)
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
      
 }    

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        <input id="lat"/>
        <input id="lng"/>
        <input id="add"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `geocodePosition` function from [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828044/how-to-get-the-formated-address-from-a-dragged-marker-in-google-version-maps), change it to update your `<input>`.  Call it in your "center_changed" function.

```
function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      $('#add').val(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      $('#add').val('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

//Retrive the center location
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "center_changed", function() {
  var lat = map.getCenter().lat();
  var lng = map.getCenter().lng();
  $('#lat').val(lat);
  $('#lng').val(lng);
  geocodePosition(map.getCenter())
});
```

```js
var map;
var geocoder;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    scrollwheel: true,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    scaleControl: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.038235, -98.219530),
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
    }
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);


  //Retrive the center location
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "center_changed", function() {
    var lat = map.getCenter().lat();
    var lng = map.getCenter().lng();
    $('#lat').val(lat);
    $('#lng').val(lng);
    geocodePosition(map.getCenter())
  });


  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude);
      document.getElementById('lat').value = position.coords.latitude;
      document.getElementById('lng').value = position.coords.longitude;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        title: 'Ubicación GPS',
        icon: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/operations_poligone/iconos/GPS_P06.png',
        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
      });

      map.setZoom(16);
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Turn GPS on';
  } else {
    var content = 'Try with your fingers';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(19.038235, -98.219530),
    content: content,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);

}

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      $('#add').val(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      $('#add').val('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#map-canvas {
  position: relative;
}
#map-canvas:after {
  width: 66px;
  height: 66px;
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -66px 0 0 -44px;
  background: url('https://storage.googleapis.com/operations_poligone/iconos/Stick01.png');
  background-size: 88px 66px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<input id="lat" />
<input id="lng" />
<input id="add" />
```

Comment: It works fine but I think there is something missing, when moving the map (pan) most of the times the address input says _cannot determine address_  Do I need an **update instruction** just like in the reference example? Something like this:   `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });` @geocodezip

Comment: If the reverse geocoder can't find a result, that is what the code in that example does.  Most of the places I saw that happen at were the middle of parks (where I wasn't surprised to see that.